# Java android, getting image from gallery and show it on screen (error) 

Tags: java, android, imageview, gallery

First time I post a question, so here it goes.
I want to push on a button, so it opens the gallery, pick a picture, then shows it somewhere on the screen (layout).

I got this far by now:

```
public void FotoKiezen(View v) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
     {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        if (photoUri != null)
        {
        try {
              String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
         cursor.moveToFirst();
     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
     String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
     cursor.close();
     Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
     ImageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);


     }catch(Exception e)
      {}
      }
    }// resultCode
    }// case 1
    }// switch, request code
}// public void onActivityResult
```

There is some other code above it too, but here somewhere is the problem.

I get an error on the line `ImageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);`
The error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type ImageView

I searched a lot on the internet, and tried many things, but I can't resolve it.
Maybe it is really easy and I just don't see it.

I am beginner at Java android programming, used to program in C++.
So also some explanation about the error would be very nice :D

Comment: Rather than comment your close braces, IMO it's more readable (and easier to maintain!) to just make the indentations match.

Comment: If you solved then please accept answer, which you think right one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the object of ImageView class? For example:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

or

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.<your image view id>);
img.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.
It doesn't show it on the screen yet, but the error is gone, and app isn't crashing, thanks for the fast and useful replies

Comment: You should mark it as an answer so it will benefit other people too.

Answer (score 2):

I think this line cause error..

```
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Here `ImageView` is a class, instead of this you have to create a object of it then use `setImageBitmap` to it.,

```
ImageVIew mImageView = new ImageView(this)
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Or if you have already defined ImageView object in your activity then just use that..

Comment: Thanks this worked.
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.<your image view id>);
img.setImageBitmap(bMap);

Thanks, both of you ofcourse!

[SOLVED]

Comment: @Bigflow, instead of tag the question as "SOLVED", accept the answer. More info in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)