# Image XML Parsing using sax in android

Tags: android

I want to parse the images in the xml file. i am able to parse the text but how to parse the images and display image corresponding to that text in list view.Image and Text should be in one row. My Xml file sample is below

```
<tv>
   <channel id="0240.TEN ACTION.in">
        <display-name>0: TEN ACTION+</display-name>
        <thumb_url>http://localhost/rg.jpeg</thumb_url>
   </channel>
   <channel id="2130.ENTER 10.in">
          <display-name>0: ENTER 10</display-name>
          <thumb_url>http://localhost/rg.jpeg</thumb_url>
   </channel>

 </tv>
```

Comment: Am also facing the same problem, can you tell me how to resolve this as i pasted below code but not worked

Comment: @AndroidOptimist what is your error?

Comment: when i tried am getting nothing on my screen

Comment: @AndroidOptimist Ok then, ask new Question with your code and put your error log , so that somebody will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:
First you need to get the image path from xml like any other attribute of xml and then pass that URL to this function.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Nothing too complicated – simply create a URL object using the “src” string (i.e. `String src = “http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com”)`, connect to it, and use Android’s BitmapFactory class to decode the input stream. The result should be your desired Bitmap object!

Comment: i used listview and i already parsed text and store those values in ArrayList<String> but the above code returns Bitmap so how can i add this returned bitmap to ArrayList<String>??

Comment: You don't have to store bitmap in listView, when you want to display the image in ListView, ust call this function, and set the bitmap returned from this function as imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type ImageView

Comment: pls see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094459/java-android-getting-image-from-gallery-and-show-it-on-screen-error

Comment: Yes.. But 'm not getting image in screen

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: only the the first tag "0240.TEN ACTION.in" is parsed and when it encounters the second tag <thumb_url> giving warnings and only 0240.TEN ACTION.in is in listView nothing else(even the image or text)

Comment: Post your code. The following is also a very easy to parse the xml: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Comment: SAXParserActivity sax = new SAXParserActivity();
        sax.saxparse();
     ArrayList<String> chn = new ArrayList<String>();
     chn = sax.getchannelArray();
    
     String src = sax.getThumb();
     Bitmap bitmap = SAXParserActivity.getBitmapFromURL(src);
     
     ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_chn);
     img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,chn));

Comment: Since you are retrieving a channel array, and channel array contains all the fields, so access the thumb and display name from channel. and since channel is an array, you can traverse all the channel elements in xml. Next time whenever you will post anything, don't post it in comment box, post it in your answer box.

Comment: I believe I have solved your question which you have posted. The problem now you are in, is a different problem. Then why did you rejected my answer?